# OrientDB Parsing through Traverse command's output in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, parsing, output, orientdb

I'm working with Orient DB, I'm using Java APIs to insert data and query the data. Those are working fine. But I'm not getting good documentation on the REST APIs. I want to now call Orient DB's REST API to query the data on the fly from client side javascript and consume the JSON output and display it on the frontend application.

```
              V1 
            /    \
           E1     E2
          /        \
         V2         V3
        /  \       /  \ 
      E3    E3    E4   E4
      /      \    /     \ 
     V5      V6   V7     V8
```

This is my typical/simplest of graph in my application and following are the queries whose output i need to consume in javascript.
I would like to traverse the graph from top to bottom and bottom to top with some filtering conditions on vertex properties.
1. Select from V1
2. Traverse out() from v1
3. Traverse in() from V5

In Java, I iterate over vertex.getEdges() and get to adjacent vertices like edge.getVertex(Direction.IN) at all levels of the graph.

But from the javascript i want to consume output of any query that I pass to it and get all properties of the vertex and the properties of vertices connected by all its edges.

Could someone show me how to do it, it would be great help for my project.

Comment: So you want a JavaScript function and JSON as output, is it correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, i need generic client side JavaScript which can handle json output of any query that i pass, it should understand vertex to edges relations and also should get me its vertex &/or edge properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little function:

```
var g=orient.getGraph(); 
var b=g.command("sql", myQuery);
return b;
```

And save it in Studio -> Functions:

[image]

Than you can call it via HTTP REST using this String:

```
http://localhost:2480/command/GratefulDeadConcerts/sql/select expand(result) from(select sqlFunc("select from v") as result)
```

`GratefulDeadConcerts` is DB name, `select from v` is the query you want to pass.
I have tested it in the Postman and you will get the output in JSON as you can see:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes correct, thanks for helping me here, But if I want to retrieve output of traverse query, lets say, how to easily associate a vertex, its properties and it's connected vertices & their properties. Like in my example, all vertices from v1 through v8 are all corrected by edges. I would like to get vertex and its connected vertices' properties in client side js.

Comment: Just do `traverse all() from #9:1` where #9:1 is your v1. You will get all data.

Comment: You can find more info on traverse here: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Traverse.html hope it helps!

Comment: im aware of of traverse command, may be my qestion is more on consumption of resopnse in js. So if i do

Comment: Traverse out() from v1 then in the output, we will get all associted vertices but how to link them in js as they as linked in db. What we get in output is rid of associted vertices but i need propeties of them also. I guess fetchplan does what i wanted but is that mapping doable from output of travserse, without fetchplan.

Comment: try expand() it will expand data in listed rids, see: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Functions.html#expand